# Rails Models Structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop

I'm developing a website with the following models:

```
- Restaurant
--> has_one :menu

- Menu
--> has_many :items
--> belongs_to :restaurant

- Item
--> belongs_to :menu

- Food

- Drink
```

`Food` and `Drink` are models that theoretically subclass from `Item` because each of them will have its own specific attributes. I tried the STI (Single Table Inheritance) approach but I realized that I cannot add custom fields to `Food` and `Drink` because the tables are not created.

I think this is a pretty common scenario but I'm stuck on how to implement it.

Comment: Why don't you create the table?

Comment: If `Food` and  `Drink` will have its own attribute, you need to create tables. If you are trying the STI without tables, make a method with the name for the future attribute (returning some value)

Answer (score 1):

I would approach it like this:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  belongs_to :menu

  # ...any other code that Food and Drink share...
end

class Food < Item
  self.table_name = "foods"

  # ...code specific to Food...
end

class Drink < Item
  self.table_name = "drinks"

  # ...code specific to Drink...
end
```

As you can see, the special parts are the `abstract_class` and `table_name` class methods. The [docs for the former](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance/ClassMethods.html) include this information:

> #### abstract_class
>
> Set this to true if this is an abstract class (see `abstract_class?`).
>   If you are using inheritance with ActiveRecord and don't want child
>   classes to utilize the implied STI table name of the parent class,
>   this will need to be true. For example, given the following:
>
> ```
> class SuperClass < ActiveRecord::Base
>   self.abstract_class = true
> end
> class Child < SuperClass
>   self.table_name = 'the_table_i_really_want'
> end
> ```
>
> `self.abstract_class = true` is required to make `Child<.find,.create, or any Arel method>` use `the_table_i_really_want` instead of a table called `super_classes`

Of course, you will need to implement migrations for both the `foods` and `drinks` tables.

Comment: Jordan, thanks. What do you think about using the polymorphic approach? How would I implement the foods and drinks tables manually?

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly common. Assuming that all Item's had a `name`, food has a `vegetarian` flag and `drink` has a an `alcoholic` flag. You might end up with the following fields in your `items` table:

- items

  - id
  - type # this field will have the value `Food` or `Drink`
  - name
  - vegetarian
  - alcoholic

This is fine if there aren't too many fields that are different. Because of the implementation there is also nothing stopping you accessing the `alcoholic` value of a food item.

If there are lots of different attributes between Food and Drink a common implementation would be to have something like:

```
class Item < ActiveRecordBase
class Drink < Item
  has_one :detail, class_name: :drink_detail, dependent: :destroy
  delegates :alcoholic, to: :detail
class DrinkDetail < ActiveRecordBase
class Food < Item
  has_one :detail, class_name: :food_detail, dependent: :destroy
  delegates :food, to: :detail
class FoodDetail < ActiveRecordBase
```

You would then have 3 tables:

- items

  - id
  - type
  - name
- drink_details

  - id
  - item_id
  - alcoholic
- food_details

  - id
  - item_id
  - vegetarian

Comment: Nice. What's the difference between this solution and the one with `self.abstract_class` from the other answer? I'm using Ember with Rails and I don't see how I can implement your solution. It would be a mess of models.

Comment: The first part is fairly common and simple. The multiple models actually help you keep concerns separated and you can use something like the `active_model_serializers` gem to get the data to Ember in a clean way.

Comment: As to the difference, a simple STI implementation allows you to easily get all the items and display or run queries in a single SQL query. In your case I see nothing wrong with using two database tables as menu's don't usually display Food and Drink together.

Comment: Should I add a delegate for each property that I define in the Detail models?

Comment: I would but its not necessary

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
- Restaurant
--> has_one :menu

- Menu
--> has_many :items
--> belongs_to :restaurant

- Item
--> belongs_to :menu
--> has_many :foods
--> has_many :drinks

- Food
--> belongs_to :item

- Drink
--> belongs_to :item
```

Comment: Nope. `Food` `is` an `Item`. `Drink` `is` an `Item`.

Answer (score 0):

According to my comment, if you don't have the tables yet, maybe a solution would be something like this:

```
class Menu < AR
    has_many :items
end

class Item < AR
    belongs_to :menu
end

class Food < Item        
    def name
       "French Fries"
    end
end
```

Then

```
menu.items << Food.new()
menu.items.first.name
# French Fries
```